# python parsing xml, how to get values?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I try to parse XML data in Python and struggle with extracting the values.
The data looks like this:

```
[<generic:Obs>
<generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-02"/>
<generic:ObsValue value="1.1193"/>
<generic:Attributes>
<generic:Value id="OBS_STATUS" value="A"/>
<generic:Value id="OBS_CONF" value="F"/>
</generic:Attributes>
</generic:Obs>, <generic:Obs>
<generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-03"/>
<generic:ObsValue value="1.1147"/>
<generic:Attributes>
<generic:Value id="OBS_STATUS" value="A"/>
<generic:Value id="OBS_CONF" value="F"/>
</generic:Attributes>
</generic:Obs>]
```

I would like to create a Pandas DF with columns ['Date','Value'].
A date should be the value out of `<generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-03"/>`, Value out of `<generic:ObsValue value="1.1147"/>`.
When I run the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'xml')
dates = soup.find_all("ObsDimension")
```

I'm getting the result as:

```
[<generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-02"/>,
 <generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-03"/>,
 <generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-06"/>,
 <generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-07"/>,
 <generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-08"/>,
 <generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-09"/>]
```

But how can I get the date and the corresponding value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse XML and get instances of a particular node attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-to-parse-xml-and-get-instances-of-a-particular-node-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = '''\
<data>
<generic:Obs>
<generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-02"/>
<generic:ObsValue value="1.1193"/>
<generic:Attributes>
<generic:Value id="OBS_STATUS" value="A"/>
<generic:Value id="OBS_CONF" value="F"/>
</generic:Attributes>
</generic:Obs>

<generic:Obs>
<generic:ObsDimension value="2020-01-03"/>
<generic:ObsValue value="1.1147"/>
<generic:Attributes>
<generic:Value id="OBS_STATUS" value="A"/>
<generic:Value id="OBS_CONF" value="F"/>
</generic:Attributes>
</generic:Obs>

</data>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, 'xml')

all_data = []
for obs in soup.select('Obs'):
    date = obs.ObsDimension['value']
    value = obs.ObsValue['value']
    all_data.append({'Date': date, 'Value': value})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Date   Value
0  2020-01-02  1.1193
1  2020-01-03  1.1147
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice and close example. It helped a lot and improved my understanding.